# What are the Group Policy settings to control the IE9 "Disable add-ons" toolbar that wants to disable slow add-ons?

Tags: group-policy, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

Is there a way via Group Policy (or otherwise) to prevent IE9's Disable add-ons 'toolbar' from being displayed, or control the add-on delay that causes it to show? I'm talking about the 'toolbar' that advises users they have add-ons that are slowing down the IE load time, which you can open from Command Bar > Tools > Toolbars > Disable add-ons.

So far I can't find a Group Policy that affects this. I assume that if the user doesn't have the access to disable an add-on then the window won't be shown, but can someone confirm this?

Process Monitor tells me when I change the delay via that toolbar it saves to the registry value HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAO Settings\AddonLoadTimeThreshold, but I'm not sure how I can change the default value for all users. Any suggestions?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [spreadsheet](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=9409) to find what you're after.

Comment: The policy is Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Disable add-on performance notifications